# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'imports' when using @babel/polyfill or @babel/runtime

Tags: webpack, babeljs

Using @babel 7.0.0-beta.36 with Webpack. when I include either the polyfill or the runtime library, I run into a compilation error.

Please see attached here https://gist.github.com/pathsny/af270f61390380c8d948973ed9e09787
my .babelrc, package.json, package-lock.json, and webpack.config.js

In the above gist, either uncommenting the line with the async function inside the file "offending file" or uncommenting the entry @babel/polyfill in the webpack.config.js and then compiling the code results in the error

`ERROR in ./node_modules/@babel/polyfill/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'imports' in '/project_path/node_modules/@babel/polyfill/node_modules/regenerator-runtime'
BREAKING CHANGE: It's no longer allowed to omit the '-loader' suffix when using loaders.
                 You need to specify 'imports-loader' instead of 'imports',
                 see https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#automatic-loader-module-name-extension-removed
webpack: Failed to compile.`

I would appreciate any help figuring out what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it is caused by

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      Promise: 'imports?this=>global!exports?global.Promise!es6-promise',
      fetch: 'imports?this=>global!exports?global.fetch!whatwg-fetch'
}),
```

in `Webpack.config.js`, this should be changed to

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          Promise: 'imports-loader?this=>global!exports-loader?global.Promise!es6-promise',
          fetch: 'imports-loader?this=>global!exports-loader?global.fetch!whatwg-fetch'
}),
```

As webpack doesn't auto add the loader postfix anymore

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you!

Comment: In other words, replace all occurrences of the `imports?` string with `imports-loader?` per new syntax guidelines/requirements, a task easily automatable via Sublime Text, free online tools, and more. :)